# Get Value from Element Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following html:

```
<div class="product">
    <span class="name">Product name</span>
    <span class="price">Product price</span>
</div>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Purchase" onclick="myfunction()" />

<input type="hidden" name="p-name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="p-price" value="">
```

I am trying to build a function in javascript that takes the value from `span.name` (`span.price`) and adds it to input p-name (input p-price).

How can you do that?

Apperantly http://api.jquery.com/val/ is not working as expected.

**EDIT**

Thanks all for answering!

I've corrected the html error you guys pointed out in the comments.

Comment: What jQuery have you tried?

Comment: You have a hidden input field with an onclick, that will never fire.

Comment: `span` doesn't return anything for `.val()` because it doesn't have a `value`. Use `.text()` or `.html()` instead.

Comment: How do you click something that is not visible?

Comment: @Milanzor Maybe he has a hidden mouse. Ever think of that? Eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a button or something to fire the copying:

```
<input type="button" id="copy_values" value="Copy the values" />
```

and your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#copy_values").click(function(){
    //Change the value of the input with name "p-name" to the text of the span with class .name
    $('input[name="p-name"]').val($('.name').text());
    $('input[name="p-price"]').val($('.price').text());
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.product span').each(function () {
    var selector = 'input[name=p-' + this.className + ']';
    $(selector).val(this.innerHTML);
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uh2U2/1/)

Comment: You should mention support for `classList` though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#compat-desktop

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ true. Changed to `className`.

Answer (score 1):

For span we use **text()** function instead of **val()**

.val() is used when we use input and .text() is used when we use span in HTML. 
Reference link : http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: text() is not an attribute, it is a function. And val() can be used on many other elements than input.

Comment: ya... misprint from my side :) 
Its a function used with < span> in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

That's going to be hard to click to a HIDDEN field.

If you change input type to text, then in onclick you can write: this.value=document.getElementById('name').innerHTML; (to use this, you have to add ID with name to your )

OR, you can create a seperate button, and onclick method can be fired.